# Corner detection using EmguCv

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I'm trying to detect the corners of the image using emguCv. To do that I used Harris Corner detection method in emguCv. but output result is blurred and using that method I cannot get the number of the corners in the image. When I searching I found a code in OpenCvSharp to detect corners and It will give output as my wish. 
I tried to convert that OpenCvSharp code to EmguCv and I stuck in here. When converting 'Cv.GoodFeaturesToTrack()' method to EmguCv. In EmguCv structure it requires 11 parameters and for last 4 parameters what should I pass? Can someone help me?

OpencvSharp code as follows:

```
IplImage src;
IplImage gray;
IplImage eigImg;

        public void Grascale()
        {
            gray = Cv.CreateImage(src.Size, BitDepth.U8, 1);
            Cv.CvtColor(src, gray, ColorConversion.RgbToGray);
            Cv.SaveImage("grayimg.jpg", src);
        }

        public void DetectCorners()
        {
            Grascale();
            int cornerCount = 15000000;


            using (src)
            using (gray)
            using (IplImage eigImg = new IplImage(gray.GetSize(), BitDepth.F32, 1))
            using (IplImage tempImg = new IplImage(gray.GetSize(), BitDepth.F32, 1))

            {
                CvPoint2D32f[] corners;
                Cv.GoodFeaturesToTrack(gray, eigImg, tempImg, out corners, ref cornerCount, 0.1, 15);
                Cv.FindCornerSubPix(gray, corners, cornerCount, new CvSize(3, 3), new CvSize(-1, -1), new CvTermCriteria(20, 0.03));

                for (int i = 0; i < cornerCount; i++)
                    Cv.Circle(src, corners[i], 3, new CvColor(0, 0, 255), 2);

                Cv.SaveImage("result_img.jpg", src);

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you better use `findcountours` method. Then, `approxPolyDP` so you can get "corners" (depends on the shape), then `cornersSubPix` to approximate even more the results and apply some logic loops to group similar segments.